# CSS: transition on ease-out not working

Tags: css, hover, css-transitions

I would like the image effects on the main page to fade out on mouse-out as well as on mouseover.

I have changed 
`all 1s ease;` to: all `1s ease-in-out;` but it is still not fading out on mouse-out but it just jumps.

Site: http://wolf-photoart.witconsult.de/

Here is an example of my current CSS:

```
#mainportraits img, #mainart img, #maincomics img { max-width: 56vw; }
#mainportraits img:hover, #mainart img:hover, #maincomics img:hover{
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(50%) contrast(1.2) blur(3px) brightness(0.8); 
    -moz-filter: grayscale(50%) contrast(1.2) blur(3px) brightness(0.8); 
    -o-filter: grayscale(50%) contrast(1.2) blur(3px) brightness(0.8); 
    -ms-filter: grayscale(50%) contrast(1.2) blur(3px) brightness(0.8); 
    filter: grayscale(50%) contrast(1.2) blur(3px) brightness(0.8); 
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}

#mainportraits:after{
    content: 'Portraits';
    z-index: 9999;
    -webkit-opacity: 0;
    -moz-opacity: 0;
    opacity: 0;
} 

#mainportraits:hover:after{
  -webkit-opacity: 0.25;
  -moz-opacity: 0.25;
  opacity: 0.25;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 1s ease-in-out;   
    }
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.   Although you have provided a link to an example, if the link were to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because you used the transition property on the hover selector. You should instead put it on the image like so:

```
#mainportraits img {
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I kept the effect on the :hover:after but applied the transition directly to the img tag and it's now working as wanted.